# Calculating three differents sum in three tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, subquery

I have these tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `bookId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `books`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`bookId`),

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movements;
CREATE TABLE `movements` (
  `movementId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `movementTypeId` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `deletedFlag` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `movements`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`movementId`),
  ADD KEY `movementId` (`movementTypeId`,`deletedFlag`) USING BTREE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movements_types;
CREATE TABLE `movements_types` (
  `movementTypeId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `movements_types`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`movementTypeId`);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movements_books;
CREATE TABLE `movements_books` (
  `movementId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bookId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `bookSize` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantity` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `books` (`bookId`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'Harry Potter'),
(2, 'Mysql Join'),
(3, 'Comedy');

INSERT INTO `movements` (`movementId`, `movementTypeId`, `deletedFlag`) VALUES
(7, 1, 0),
(8, 2, 0),
(9, 2, 0);

INSERT INTO `movements_types` (`movementTypeId`, `title`) VALUES
(1, "Bought"),
(2, "Sold");

INSERT INTO `movements_books` (`movementId`, `bookId`, `bookSize`, `quantity`) VALUES
(7, 1, 1, 3),
(7, 1, 2, 3),
(7, 2, 1, 3),
(7, 2, 2, 3),
(8, 1, 1, 2),
(8, 1, 1, 2),
(9, 2, 1, 3);
```

bookSize is just an integer indicating the size of the book.

movements_books actually has 111824 records, movements has 4534.
deletedFlag is 1 for a deleted movement (I prefer to keep them flagged) and 0 otherwise.

I need help creating indexes and I need these results:

1) sizes sold/bought/available for each book (bookId, bookSize, booksSold, booksBought, booksBought minus booksSold)

2) books sold/bought/available for each book of all size (bookId, booksSold, booksBought, booksBought minus booksSold)

To get the one of the statistics I tried:

```
SELECT 
   books.title
   movements_books_grouped.bookId,
   SUM(IF(movements.movementTypeId=1, movements_books_grouped.quantity, NULL)) AS booksBought,
   SUM(IF(movements.movementTypeId=2, movements_books_grouped.quantity, NULL)) AS booksSold,
   (
       SUM(IF(movements.movementTypeId=1, movements_books_grouped.quantity, 0))- 
       SUM(IF(movements.movementTypeId=2, movements_books_grouped.quantity, 0)) 
   ) AS booksAvailability,
   FROM 
   (
   SELECT bookId,quantity,movementId FROM movements_books GROUP BY bookId
   ) AS movements_books_grouped 
   JOIN movements ON movements.movementId=movements_books_grouped.movementId
   JOIN books ON books.bookId=movements_books_grouped.bookId
   GROUP BY movements_books_grouped.bookId
   ORDER BY book.title
```

but it's very slow.
Edit: I needed to add another table to the example because that's the one that makes really slow the last query. I need to join to this table because I need to order the result by title.

Comment: I can't post my real tables because I would have to explain each field and it would take a lot of writing since I would have to explain the entire project. The "book" example is identical to my case and it doesn't need much explanation

Comment: Do I really need to write CREATE and INSERT statements for 3 tables and 7 fields in total which are 6 integer and 1 string?

Comment: I just edited and added a MRE (I hope it's good)

Comment: Views in MySQL cannot use an index, making them (in my view) almost useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that can use indexes:

```
SELECT m.movementId
     , m.movementTypeId
     , m.deletedFlag
     , mb.bookId
     , mb.bookSize
     , t.title
  FROM movements m
  JOIN movements_types t 
    ON t.movementTypeId = m.movementTypeId
  JOIN movements_books mb
    ON mb.movementid = m.movementid
 WHERE m.deletedFlag=0;
```

An index on (m.movementTypeId, m.deletedFlag) *may* prove beneficial, but best to suck it and see.

Comment: Very clear, thank you. Can you also suggest me a query to get at least one of the statistics? I tried a query that I wrote in the question post, but it's really slow.

Comment: See the points above again. Three things were requested, remember?

Comment: You mean the points against the view? They are clear, I don't want to use them and removed them from the original post. I just can't get the query to SUM all the quantities for the statistics.